# Python3: Editing data acquired with urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I wrote a program with urllib that gets all article titles from a webpage (in this case nytimes.com). There is only one problem. Some titles have a semicolon, which results in an ugly "There\xe2\x80\x99s" if printed. So I tried to replace the \xe2\x80\x99 with a ' but it does not seem to work. I think there is a problem with Tuples. Unfortunately I can't create a tuple, that results in the same problem.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)' 

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
resp_data = resp.read()
par = re.findall(r'story-heading"><a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>',str(resp_data))

for n in par:
print(n[1])
print(n[1].replace("\xe2\x80\x99","'"))
```

I tried to create string variables from the tuple but nothing is working. I know there is another solution to this with BeautifulSoup but I thought I'd try to find my own way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this one line:

```
resp_data = resp.read()
```

to:

```
resp_data = resp.read().decode("utf8")
```

And the work will be done.

**Explication**:

The website is using `ut8` encoding, as i'm guessing, so you have to `decode` the returned bytes into an `utf8` string which can be better represented like what you intended to have.

**PS:** You can use `resp.read().decode()` without an argument in `decode()` method and you let `Python` guessing the encoding type.

Comment: Hope it is helping you. You can upvote and/or accept this answer if its satisfying your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the repr() of the string, hence the funny characters. If you want, coerce this to a string. See my results:

```
>>> print repr(n[1])
'There\xe2\x80\x99s'
>>> print str(n[1])
There’s
```

In Summary: wrap your n[1] in str()

Comment: I tried this already and unfortunately this will not solve the problem. Nevertheless I aprec. your will to help. Cheers